# How to update properties file using pom.xml through command line

Tags: spring, maven, command-line-interface, pom.xml, properties-file

This is my properties file where i have added this variable
**databaseEnabled=${db.activedb}**

Path of my properties file
**src/main/resources/application-dev.properties**

This is my `pom.xml` where I have added this code

```
<build>
    <finalName>spring-boot</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dynamo</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dynamo</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <db.activedb>dynamodb</db.activedb>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mongo</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>mongo</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <db.activedb>mongodb</db.activedb>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: and what is your question? Read [ask] and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Add `includes` tag:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>/application-dev.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

To set profile using `-P` option:

`mvn package -P mongo`

To check result open `target/classes/application.properties` file.

Comment: it's okay but when i try to access in my code like   @Value("${databaseEnabled}") 
  private String databaseEnabled;i get   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.activedb' in string value "${db.activedb}"